# Running multiple sql queries to get matrix results in .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to fetch results from database to generate some kind of matrix results to send back to front end. The point is that I have percentile value for X and Y axes which I divide into 10 parts to have 10x10 table. To get each value I calculate distinct user Ids, so it goes like 1-1, 1-2 ... 10-10.

This is my current code (unfinished though, just the idea what I have so far) which I want to improve because running 100 queries one after one doesn't seem like a nice solution. However I am a little bit stuck how to make the performance better and whether I should return results in dictionary with lenght=100, or multidimensional matrix array to make it a good practice code. Thanks anyone for the tips in advance, my code is below:

```
public async Task GenerateMatrix(List<double> x, string xAxis, List<double> y, string yAxis, Parameters parameters)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> xDict = GenerateRanges(x, parameters.XAxis);
            IDictionary<string, string> yDict = GenerateRanges(y, parameters.YAxis);
            
            var innerJoin = GenerateInnerJoin(parameters);
            var whereClauses = GenerateWhereClause(parameters);
            
            var sql = $@"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [dbo].[{nameof(Table)}].[{nameof(Table.UserId)}]) FROM [dbo].[{nameof(Table)}] {innerJoin} ";
            if (whereClauses.Any())
            {
                sql += " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", whereClauses);
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                var queryToExecute = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < y.Count; j++)
                {
                    queryToExecute = sql + " AND " + xDict.Values.ElementAt(i) + " AND " + yDict.Values.ElementAt(j);
                    var userCount = await Store().QueryScalar<int>(queryToExecute);
                }
            }
            
            return null;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> GenerateRanges(List<double> axis, string columnTitle)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < axis.Count; i++)
            {
                var rangeSql = $@" [dbo].[{nameof(Table)}].[{columnTitle}]";
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    d.Add(axis[i].ToString(), rangeSql + " < " + axis[i]);
                }
                else if (i == axis.Count - 1)
                {
                    d.Add(axis[i] + "+", rangeSql + " > " + axis[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    d.Add(axis[i-1] + "-" + axis[i], rangeSql + " > " + axis[i-1] + " AND " + rangeSql + " < " + axis[i]);
                }
            }
            return d;
        }
```

sql looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT [dbo].[Table].[UserId]) 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE  Table.[ClientId] = '2' 
    AND  [dbo].[Table].[ProbabilityAlive] < 0.1 
    AND  [dbo].[Table].[SpendAverage] < 24.86
```

so there's going to be 100 hundred of lines like this.
`ProbabilityAlive` and `SpendAverage` are column titles that come from front end, there could be any other column titles.
For these two columns I calculate percentile value, which then I divide into ten parts, one being X axis, another being Y axis. and then I use sql query from above to get value for each matrix value which becomes 100 queries since the matrix is 10x10.

As a result I want to get 100 integer values I am still trying to figure out whether it's best to put data in dictionary and then have key with range x-y and value as select result (e.g.  `"0-1", 5472"`), or whether to put it in multidimensional array or something else. I have `xDict`  that contains range as a key e.g. "0-1" and then sql sentence ProbabilityAlive > 0 AND ProbabilityALive <1 and then add same for Y axis from `yDict`. Then I have two lists `x` and `y` that contain 10 double values that are used for these ranges

Comment: This is a 100% SQL question but the actual SQL query is missing. Explain what you actually want to do, with sample data and results. Perhaps all you need is a `WITH ROLLUP` expression in a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: yes @AndrewMorton

Comment: You didn't explain what the data looks like or what you expect yet. The code doesn't help at all. Only the first paragraph and the query are relevant, but they don't seem to be related. What percentiles? T-SQL has percentile functions like [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that could be used to return various percentiles in a row. You could create a query that returns 100 rows with the X,Y and percentile data you want, but what *do* you want? Where do the X and Y values come from?

Comment: Are you trying to generate buckets for the `ProbabilityAlive` and `ProbabilityAlive` fields and generate percentiles (or percentages?) of unique clients for each combination?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated my answer, hope it's clearer now

Comment: Not really. You're describing the code, not what you actually want to get as output, what the data looks like, and what the desired output is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to calculate the user counts for specific ranges of `ProbabilityAlive` and `SpendAverage`.

First, you need to generate the range combinations. The easy way to generate combinations in SQL is to join two tables or sets of values.

If you had two tables with the range values like these:

```
create table  ProbabilityRanges
(
    LowBound decimal(3,2), UpperBound(3,2)
) 

create table SpendRanges
(
    LowBound decimal(3,2), UpperBound(3,2)
)
```

You could use a cross-join to generate all the combinations:

```
SELECT 
    SpendRanges.LowBound as SLow,
    SpendRanges.UpperBound as SUpper,
    ProbabilityRangers.LowBound as PLow, 
    ProbabilityRanges.UpperBound as PUpper
FROM ProbabilityRanges CROSS JOIN SpeedRanges
```

You can use those combinations to filter and count the rows in another table that are within those bounds:

```
SELECT 
    SpendRanges.LowBound as SpendValue,
    SpendRanges.LowBound as ProbabilityValue, 
    Count(DISTINCT UserID) as Count
FROM SomeTable CROSS JOIN ProbabilityRanges CROSS JOIN SpeedRanges
Where 
    SomeTable.ClientID=2 
    AND SomeTable.SpendAverage >=SpeedRanges.LowBound 
        AND SpendAverage < SpeedRanges.UpperBound
    AND SomeTable.ProbabilityAlive >= ProbabilityRangers.LowBound 
        AND   SomeTable.ProbabilityAlive < ProbabilityRanges.UpperBound
GROUP BY SpendRanges.LowBound,SpendRanges.LowBound
```

It's possible to create the bounds dynamically for a specific number of bins, eg using a Numbers table. You'll have to provide more information on what you actually want though

Answer (score 0):

With just two dimensions, easiest to do & maintain, would be to make a TSQL Stored Procedure that outputs a Tuple (the default output) of what you want.
Pass in as parameters what you got as input from the Front-End.

What if you had that functionality with a web-service HTTP GET returning a JSON (or XML)?
Simulate it with TSQL instead.

Since you have direct access to the SQL Server, you call a Stored Procedure of type "get" that you pass parameters, and get a Tuple result.
Easy to write & test independently of your .Net core application. Will be very fast also.

type "get" = just a read-only SP, I name mine USP_GET_method_name.
I also use SPs for saving with SQL-side validations, so I call them USP_PUT_method_name.

Cheers

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There's no reason to create a stored procedure either - it *won't* change how queries execute or what is returned. A stored procedure can be used to move complex code from the application to the query, but won't change what that query actually does

Comment: And mixing up HTTP and HTTP verbs with databases is not helping at all

Comment: I humbly disagree, TSQL is much better at rendering a Matrix-style output directly as a Tuple for .Net to consume, than looping within .Net.
Naming convention to distinguish SPs that are tied to Front-End, versus, purely back-end.
FWIW, this is very similar to what we do with SSIS (using SPs).

Comment: You didn't answer the question. You just described your custom naming convention. And SSIS has nothing to do with either HTML or executing analytic queries, it's an ETL tool

Comment: Actually wanted to post as a comment and not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: Don't post the answer then. The rule is there for a reason - to get new users familiar with Q&A sites like StackOverflow before they start commenting. 50 rep is a tiny number too. This wouldn't make a good comment either though, it's not relevant to the question